# Drill-down tableview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

So basically i want to achieve this form of tableview as shown in the sketch.

[image]

I have a **MasterTableViewController** with an array of people's names.
When a user selects **Person 2**, it then presents a detail of that **Person 2's** details such as **Name**, **Age**, **Location**, and **Status**.

If so the user views that and clicks the **Back** button, they can choose another Person and view their own details different than **Person 2**.

I been having trouble with this for the past 2 weeks and i cannot figure it out. I been looking all over the internet but nothing. Any help will greatly help. Or a sample swift Xcode project in a zipped file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one class which holds person data like this:

```
class People {
var name: String?
var age : Int?
var location: String?
var status: String?

init(name: String, age: Int, location: String, status: String) {

    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.location = location
    self.status = status
   }
}
```

After that you can add data this way:

```
func setUpPersons(){

    let person1 = People(name: "Anna", age: 20, location: "12312321", status: "Single")
    let person2 = People(name: "John", age: 30, location: "12312321", status: "Single")
    let person3 = People(name: "Leo", age: 30, location: "12312321", status: "Single")
    let preson4 = People(name: "Dharmesh", age: 30, location: "12312321", status: "Single")
    arrayOfPerson.append(person1)
    arrayOfPerson.append(person2)
    arrayOfPerson.append(person3)
    arrayOfPerson.append(preson4)
}
```

Then you can display person name into tableview cell this way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
    let person = arrayOfPerson[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = person.name
    return cell
}
```

You can get selected cell Index this way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
}
```

After that you can pass data with segue this way:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard") {

        var detailViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController)
        let person = arrayOfPerson[selectedIndex]

        detailViewController.nameP = person.name!
        detailViewController.ageP = person.age!
        detailViewController.locationP = person.location!
        detailViewController.statusP = person.status!
    }
}
```

And this way you can display data of selected person:

```
    class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var age: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!

    var nameP = ""
    var ageP = 0
    var locationP = ""
    var statusP = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(nameP)
        name.text = nameP
        age.text = "\(ageP)"
        location.text = locationP
        status.text = statusP
    }

}
```

[HERE](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Person-Class) is your sample Project.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what i wanted. know i must figure a way from this sample project on how to add the names and store them in an array rather than hardcoding them. Thank you so much Dharmesh Kheni :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is add a segue between your `MasterTableView` and your `DetailView`, which is triggered when you click on a table cell. The `DetailView` controller logic should have `name`, `age`, `location`, and `status` properties which can be set in your `MasterTableView` controller in a `prepareForSegue` function.

See [this](http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/) for an example.

Comment: Yeah, I mean i know that those properties belong in the DetailView, what about the MasterTableView's data for each of its person? Such as Person 2, or Person 4, each of those cells need to have their own data different from one another.

Comment: You keep an array of `Person` objects in the `MasterTableView` controller. Checkout out the link I posted. `swiftblogs` in your case would contain an array of `Person` objects instead of `String` objects.

Comment: Yes, I also have a Person array that contains the people list. Here it is: var People = ["Mark", "Brian", "Mike", "Nate", "Lee"]. This array shows in my UITableViewController and when accessing "Nate", it needs to show Nate's age, and all the following data pertaining to Nate. I feel that i need to add a nested Array of items for Nate in order for them to display in the DetailsView but i don't know how to do that.